# WEP fake authentication purpose

Tags: wifi, wep

I am studying WEP protocol and more specifically fake authentication attack. Man page says

```
This is only useful when you need an associated MAC address in various aireplay-ng
attacks and there is currently no associated client.
```

Whereas the whole point of the attack is to authenticate by capturing an authentication, and retrieving from it the *keystream*, then from *keystream*, being able to create a response based on AP challenge as explained [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2007/471.pdf#section.5.2).

So I am struggling to understand how would it be useful, as it requires first an authenticated user to de-authenticate to capture the challenge/response, and considering that man says this is only useful when there is no associated client ? What's the purpose of this attack then, apart to authenticate (and then not be able to do anything, as only 128 bytes of *keystream* is revealed ?)